# how to display the contents of a file from highest to lowest

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, math, slickquiz

```
option= input("alphabetically(a), high to low(b)")
if option == "a":
    with open('Class4.txt', 'r') as r:
        for line in sorted(r):
            print(line)

elif option == "b":
            def score(line):
                return int(line.split(',')[1])

            with open('Class4.txt', 'r') as r:
                for line in sorted(r, key=score, reverse=True):
                    print(line)
```

I was able to display aplhabetically but was not able to display high to low
the file class 4 contains variable name and score

ab 9

z 4

b 6

a10

Comment: Is that the exact contents of your Class4.txt file? Why are you doing `line.split(",")` when the file doesn't have any commas in it?

Comment: You are splitting on commas instead of whitespace.

Comment: yes thats the exact contents

Comment: @Kevin if i remove the coma should that solve the problem

Comment: @python, I don't know, when you remove it does your code start working?

Comment: @Kevin when i remove the error message goes ut nothing is displasyed

Comment: Wait, there was an error message? You didn't mention that before. What did it say?

Comment: @Kevin it said Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a\Desktop\Computing ca\task 3 aplha.py", line 14, in <module>
    for line in sorted(r, key=score, reverse=True):
  File "C:\Users\a\Desktop\Computing ca\task 3 aplha.py", line 11, in score
    return int(line.split(","))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Answer (score 0):

The file contains empty lines and you are trying to split it into a list and accessing the second element. This is why you are getting IndexError.
So ignore the empty lines.

And also you should do line.split() since there is no comma

```
option= input("alphabetically(a), high to low(b)")
if option == "a":
    with open('Class4.txt', 'r') as r:
        for line in sorted(r):
            print(line)

elif option == "b":
        def score(line):
            if line != '\n':
                return int(line.split()[1])

        with open('Class4.txt', 'r') as r:
            for line in sorted(r, key=score, reverse=True):
                print(line)
```

Comment: hi the code display displays it  in alphabetical order even if b is chosen it just displays it backwards

Comment: for this particular data the result for both options is same. Try with some other data then you will see the difference